# Phototransistor interface to PIC

Tags: microcontroller, pic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTrhCm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Electronical novice (but Advanced Idiot) here. Trying to interface a [phototransistor](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/143/EAALST05RDMA0-737732.pdf) to a Microchip PIC I/O pin. Per the phototransistor's datasheet, I'm feeding +5V into the collector and have a resistor between the emitter and GND. When the emitter isn't connected to the PIC, a voltmeter on the emitter reads nicely between near-0V to +5V with varying light exposure. But when I tie the emitter to the PIC, that range drops to a maximum of less than +0.5V. Changing the resistor value or swapping the resistor to the collector side (emitter then is to GND) and measuring there doesn't seem to make a difference. Setting the pin up for ADC or not doesn't either. TRIS definitely has it set as input though. Looking online, seems like lots of circuits showing the hardware as I have it. Is it something about the PIC? I'm sure it's something dead simple. Suggestions? Rebukes?

Comment: Please provide a link to the datasheet for the phototransistor you are using, and draw a schematic of your circuit using the built-in schematic editor. Also, specify the resistor value(s) that you have tried.

Comment: Do you have any other modules enabled in the PIC? Some modules will override the TRIS settings if they need to use those specific pins.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I've tried various ones from (a much too low) 10 ohm all the way up to 1 meg.  Even used a multi-turn precision 1 meg pot in case there was a sweet spot.

Comment: Remove your circuit and connect a 1.0K - 4.7K resistor from the PIC pin to Vcc.  If the PIC pin is set to an output, it will sink 1 - 5 mA and be low without overheating.

Comment: If you have not made any mistakes, it's possible you've physically damaged the port pin circuitry and it is now shorted to ground.

Comment: OK, as a precaution I replaced the PIC and methodically did some tests. I've just found that if I set the pin as a basic input and have it look for simply a high or low from the phototransistor, then it works fine -- that is, the voltage on the pin is about the same 0V -- +5V as when the phototransistor is isolated from the pin. So it seems to be something about configuring the pin as an ADC that causes it to pull down the voltage. Weird, right?  So it's something fundamentally dumb I'm doing in code (likely) or there's a bug in the PIC silicon (not likely). Off to the datasheet!  :)

Comment: When a PIC pin is configured for ADC input the signal path connects the GPIO pin to the ADC sample capacitor using an internal analog switch to select just one of the GPIO pins. Another test you can try is to select a different ADC channel to see if it's the ADC sample capacitor or analog switch that is the cause of your issues.